# Mostrar resultado de métodos en JLabel

Tags: java, jframe, netbeans-8.2, jlabel

tengo un JFrame en donde tengo seteados métodos (consultas de bases de datos) en algunos botones, y la idea es que el resultado de estos métodos se muestren en un JLabel. Cabe mencionar que los métodos de los botones arrojan su resultado perfectamente por consola cuando se ejecuta el jframe.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

```
    private void btnLiderMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    lider();        // TODO add your handling code here:
    VistaRequerimientosReto4.requerimiento4();
    System.out.println();
}                                     

private void btnProyectoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    proyecto();       // TODO add your handling code here:
    VistaRequerimientosReto4.requerimiento1();
    System.out.println();
}                                        

private void btnSumaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    suma();        // TODO add your handling code here:
    VistaRequerimientosReto4.requerimiento3();
    System.out.println();
}                                    

private void btnLimpiarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    limpiar();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void btnSalirMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    salir();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                  

private void lider() {
    lblSalida.setText("lider");
    
}

private void proyecto() {
    lblSalida.setText("proyecto");
    
}

private void suma() {
    lblSalida.setText("suma");
    
}

private void limpiar() {
    lblSalida.setText("");
}

private void salir() {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que lo mas optimo es usar un JTextArea para mostrar todos los datos recibidos, y con el método append para insertarlos, lo digo porque un JLabel no tiene saltos de linea para separar por registro como lo hace la consola, a menos que se lo agregues con HTML que no es nada común.

Comment: NetBeans no es sinónimo de Java. Quita esa etiqueta, pues la deberías presentar cuando tengas problemas con el IDE, no con el lenguaje

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que lo mas optimo es usar JTextArea o un JTable pero si vas a usar un JLabel, a este no le funcionan los saltos con \n, porque queda como un texto de una sola línea, la única forma que descubrí hace tiempo para crear los ToolTip de los componentes, es hacerlo con HTML, por suerte funciona con los texto del JLabel también.

Se necesita una forma de convertir el texto a HTML (sin body ni nada de eso) muy simple, uso un método:

```
public String toHtmlText(String text) {
    text = text.replace("<html>","").replace("</html>","");
    text = text.replace("\n","<br>");
    return "<html>"+text+"</html>";
}
```

Y al JLabel hay que agregarle el texto que ya tenia mas lo nuevo, con una concatenación.

```
label.setText(toHtmlText(label.getText()+"Java Swing, JFrame \n"));
label.setText(toHtmlText(label.getText()+"Java Swing, JPanel \n"));
label.setText(toHtmlText(label.getText()+"Java Swing, JTextArea \n"));
```

De esta manera con un solo JLabel se pueden tener multiples saltos de línea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo escribo como respuesta por si te sirve y necesitas usar JLabel para mostrar varias columnas y filas de la base de datos, con saltos de línea por cada registro.

Answer (score 4):

Para mostrar los valores puedes obtener el texto actual del `JLabel` obteniendolo mediante `lblSalida.getText()` y concatenar el nuevo valor, por ejemplo:

```
...
...
private void lider() {
    lblSalida.setText(lblSalida.getText() + "\n" + "lider");
    
}

private void proyecto() {
    lblSalida.setText(lblSalida.getText() + "\n" + "proyecto");
    
}

private void suma() {
    lblSalida.setText(lblSalida.getText() + "\n" + "suma");
    
}
...
...
```